# Cloudant Query text "LIKE" search on a single field

Tags: cloudant

I wish to use Cloudant Query to get all the documents wuth the specified field is matched with a string (similar to SQL "LIKE") but I just can't figure out how to do it.

I realize I can use Search Index for this purpose but I would love to know the solution using Cloudant Query.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `$regex` operator, which allows you to use a regular expression pattern. For example,

```
{
    "selector": {
        "person": {
            "$regex": "Rob"
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "person"
    ]
}
```

Additional info:
https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html#condition-operators

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. What if I want to search across two fields in a documents given a string? I can't use { "index": {}, "type": "text" } as I will then search thru the entire doc.

Comment: This will fail for the larger dataset.Cloudant doesn't use index when we use $regex even the field is indexed.

Answer (score 1):

To search multiple fields, you can use Cloudant Query's combination operators, for example:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "$or": [
      { "person": { "$regex": "Rob" }},
      { "pet":  { "$regex": "Rob" }}
    ]
  },
  "fields": [
    "person",
    "pet"
  ]
}
```

For more info, see https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html#combination-operators